# I'm trying to take out the Titles on my LogActivity Android Studio

Tags: android

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/228704/23704199/b79d14ba-03d1-11e7-85e4-350c48be11f6.png

I want to take out all of the things in the picture that are crossed out, here is my code below, thank you.

```
package pkc.trafficquest.sccapstone.trafficquest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class LogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<String> accidentList; // used for the String version of the accident list
private ArrayList<Accidents> accidents; // used for the list of type Accidents
private ListView listView;
private String csvString;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_MAIN = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log);
    Intent logIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle data = logIntent.getExtras();
    // checks to see if there is data from the intent, if there is, instantiate list of names and set up the list view
    if (logIntent.getExtras() != null){
        accidentList = logIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("accidentList");
        accidents = data.getParcelableArrayList("logAccidentList");
        ListAdapter accAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.accident_list, accidentList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aListview);
        listView.setAdapter(accAdapter);
        csvString = createCSV(accidents); // makes a csv out of the list of accidents

    }

   /*  // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();*/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.log_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { // menu to select between downloading or emailing a csv of requested accidents
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_download){ // downloads csv of requested accidents if selected
        saveCSV(csvString);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.action_email){ // downloads and emails csv of requested accidents if selected
        sendEmail(csvString);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/*
    Creates a csv file for the list of requested accidents
    @param A list of accidents to create a csv for
    @return the csv of requested accidents
     */
public String createCSV(ArrayList<Accidents> accList){
    String csv = "";
    for (int i=0; i<accList.size(); i++){ // loop through all accidents and add each detail to the csv
        Accidents accident = accList.get(i); // get individual accident
        csv += "\"" + accident.getPoint().getCoordinates().get(0) + ", " + accident.getPoint().getCoordinates().get(1) + "\"," + // add latitude and longitude, separated by a space to the list
               "\"" + accident.getToPoint().getCoordinates().get(0) + ", " + accident.getToPoint().getCoordinates().get(1) + "\"," + // add the toPoint(where the accident ends) to the list, latitude and longitude separated with a space
                accident.getDescription() + "," + // add the accident description to the list
                accident.getRoadClosed() + "," + // add if road is closed (boolean value)
                interpretSeverity(accident) + "," + // add severity of accident to list
                interpretTime(accident.getStart()) + "," + // add the start time of accident to list
                interpretTime(accident.getEnd()) + "," + // add the end time of accident to list
                interpretType2(accident) + "\n"; // add the type of the accident to the list (accident, weather, hazard, etc.) and go to next line
        String startTime = "Start Time: 03/08/2017";//interpretTime(accident.getStart());
        String startTimeWithoutTitle= startTime.substring(startTime.indexOf(":")+1,startTime.length());
        String severity = "Severity: Minor";
        String severityWithoutTitle= severity.substring(severity.indexOf(":")+1,severity.length());

        String cvs=startTimeWithoutTitle+","+severityWithoutTitle;


        System.out.println(cvs); //just for testing
    }
    return csv; // return the String in csv format
}

/*
Write the file to internal storage
@param data String data to write
 */
public void saveCSV(String data) {
    File file = null;
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // path of root directory
    if (root.canWrite()) { // checks if the application can modify the path
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AccidentData"); // new directory
        dir.mkdirs();
        file = new File(dir, "data.csv"); // file to be wrote to
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file); // output stream to file location
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.write(data.getBytes()); // write encoded string to file
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.close(); // close output stream
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File failed to write.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // prints message if file does not write to file
    }
}


/*
Interprets the time into a human readable format
@param t the string from the accident list to interpret
@return the converted time
 */
public String interpretTime (String t) {
    String timeString = t.substring(6, t.length()-2); // gets rid of the leading and trailing slashes and parenthesis
    String date; // value to return
    long time = Long.parseLong(timeString); // parse the string as a long
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' HH:mm z"); // sets the format
    date = sdf.format(new Date(time)); // sets the entered string as the SimpleDateFormat

    return date; // return the date
}

/*
Interprets the severity codes received from the request
@param acc the accident to get the severity data from
@return the interpreted severity code
 */
public String interpretSeverity (Accidents acc) {
    int severity = acc.getSeverity(); // the type code from the accident
    String sevString; // the value to return
    switch (severity) {
        case 1: sevString = "Low Impact";
            break;
        case 2: sevString = "Minor";
            break;
        case 3: sevString = "Moderate";
            break;
        case 4: sevString = "Serious";
            break;
        default: sevString = "Incorrect value";
            break;
    }
    return sevString; // return the severity code
}

/*
interprets what each type code means
@param acc The Accidents object to get the type code from
@return the interpreted type of accident
 */
public String interpretType2(Accidents acc){
    int type = acc.getType2(); // the type code from the accident
    String typeString; // the value to return
    switch (type) {
        case 1: typeString = "Accident";
            break;
        case 2: typeString = "Congestion";
            break;
        case 3: typeString = "Disabled Vehicle";
            break;
        case 4: typeString = "Mass Transit";
            break;
        case 5: typeString = "Miscellaneous";
            break;
        case 6: typeString = "Other News";
            break;
        case 7: typeString = "Planned Event";
            break;
        case 8: typeString = "Road Hazard";
            break;
        case 9: typeString = "Construction";
            break;
        case 10: typeString = "Alert";
            break;
        case 11: typeString = "Weather";
            break;
        default: typeString = "Incorrect value";
            break;
    }
    return typeString;
}

/*
Will create an email intent, and send the requested csv file after it creates it, to the email intent.
@param data String data to send as csv
 */
public void sendEmail(String data) {
    File file = null;
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // path of root directory
    if (root.canWrite()) { // checks if the application can modify the path
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AccidentData"); // new directory
        dir.mkdirs();
        file = new File(dir, "data.csv"); // file to be wrote to
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file); // output stream to file location
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.write(data.getBytes()); // write encoded string to file
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.close(); // close output stream
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File failed to write.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // prints message if file does not write to file
    }

    Uri u = null;
    u = Uri.fromFile(file); // get contents of file
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); // create an intent to send the csv
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "TrafficQuest: CSV"); // subject of email
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here is a csv, as you requested."); // body of email
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u); // add the attachment csv
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain"); // sets type to plain, supports csv files

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email with:"));

}

public void toastMaker(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

}

Comment: what exactly you want?i dont get your question

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of everything that is crossed out on the picture that I link.

Comment: How is this related to firebase?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
String data=interpretTime(accident.getStart());
String[] parts = data.split(":");
String part1 = parts[0]; //contains the title 
String part2 = parts[1]; //your data
```

The idea is to split the string using ":" as separator and somehow save the parts that you need.

Other way using part of your code assuming that interpretTime(accident.getStart()) is returning a string:

```
String startTime = interpretTime(accident.getStart()); 
String startTimeWithoutTitle= startTime.substring(startTime.indexOf(":")+1,startTime.length);
```

here you can read how substring method works [substring(int,int)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_substring_index.htm)

Comment: still seeing the same results any other ideas?

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: I took in directly and put it right under interpretType2 before the return csv

Comment: I edited it, is that what you meant it too look like?

Comment: I'm also getting errors with data.indexOf and length

Comment: I eddited once again hoping it is easier to understand what I'm trying to do. You need to figure out how to implement it in your code. Create a variable for each value that you want to display in your screen and do the same that I did and then use those variables when you create the csv.

Comment: Wait... where are you actually attaching those values to your Log.Activity?

Comment: yes I was, I added it below the code I originally had

Comment: I get that I need one for each variable but, I'm confused on where to put it and I'm still getting the length error and don't know why.

Comment: Then you need to edit the content of accidentList within the onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

I think we are missing something, all I see in the code you posted is a concatenation of the data you are getting from your accidents list. As I understand you want to take out titles from you LogActiviry that for me it means you want to display just the data without a label, if this is the case then we need the code where you set the textto the TextViews in your activity.

In other hand if you want to build a csv concatenating just the data it would be something like this:

```
String startTime = "Sart Time: 03/08/2017";//interpretTime(accident.getStart()); 
String startTimeWithoutTitle= startTime.substring(startTime.indexOf(":")+1,startTime.length());
String severity = "Severity: Minor";
String severityWithoutTitle= severity.substring(severity.indexOf(":")+1,severity.length());

String cvs=startTimeWithoutTitle+","+severityWithoutTitle;


System.out.println(cvs); //just for testing
```

In both cases this aproach can work

Comment: ok sorry I didn't see this last night I'll test it out tonight and get back to you thanks for the help

Comment: and your assumption was correct about displaying the data by itself

Comment: I uploaded my whole LogActivity maybe that will make it easier to help me

Comment: My doubt is that if you want to take the titles out of your Log screen or if you want it out of your cvs file.

Comment: I just want the titles off the page like the picture, but I have no idea how to do that.